# Scala hit GC overhead when running large external process

Tags: scala, garbage-collection

I have an external program which generate some data I need. Usually, I redirect its output to a file, then read it from my Scala application, e.g.

> app.exe > output.data

Now, I want to integrate the process, so I did

```
val stream = "app.exe" lineStream
stream foreach { line => doWork(_) }
```

Unfortunately, I got **GC overhead** exception after a while. This `app.exe` may generate very large output files, e.g. over 100MB. So I think during the streaming, Scala has been creating/destroying the `line` string instance thousands of times, and cause the overhead.

I know I can tune the JVM variables to increase the GC overhead throttling. But I am looking for a way that it doesn't need to create a lot of small `line` instances.

Comment: What the hell is a `GC overheat`?

Comment: I think you meant [GC overhead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded).

Comment: I like GC overheat better :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably due to memoization, which is a side effect of foreach-ing over a stream this way.  Effectively, you are rooting the whole file in memory.

See lots and lots of info on how to avoid this here: http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/programming/scala/stream-hygiene-i-avoiding-memory-leaks/

Specifically, you are violating rule #1.  Try defining your stream as a `def`, not a `val`.